# FreeRTOS : Create Tasks but don't start Scheduler

Tags: task

I'm using FreeRTOs on Arduino for the first time. In my setup(), i would like to create my tasks but i have few more configuration to do after so i would like to create my tasks but don't start the scheduler immediately.
This is my code currently with xTaskCreate and vTaskScheduler, but my code start the task immediately when they are created :

```
   //Create Tasks
   s1 = xTaskCreate(TaskAcquisition, NULL, configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, NULL, 2, &Acquisition);
   s2 = xTaskCreate(TaskStockage,NULL,configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE + 200, NULL, 1, &Stockage);


.... Some more config


   Serial.println(F("Config finished"));

  //Check errors
  if(fifoData==NULL || fifoSpace == NULL || s1 != pdPASS || s2 != pdPASS){
  Serial.println(F("Creation error"));
  while(1);
  }
  Serial.println(F("Fifo and Tasks created"));

  //starting
  vTaskStartScheduler();

  //if the scheduler start the code don't came here
  Serial.println(F("Ram issue"));
  while(1);
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is entirely about FreeRTOS, and not at all about the Arduino on which that is running.  You really need to seek help in a FreeRTOS forum.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `vTaskSuspend` the tasks immediately after creating them.

Then when you need a task to run you `vTaskResume` it.